# I am trying to add lines said by a character to an empty list and print it out

Tags: python, list

I am trying to add lines said by a character to an empty list and print it out..but each time I run the code it prints back an empty list "[]"....but it's supposed to print out the lines said by the character inside the list..

```
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\Desktop\\headfirstpython\\chapter3")


man = []
other = []
try:
    data=open('sketch.txt')
    for each_line in data:
        try:
            (role, line_spoken) = each_line.split(':', 1)
            line_spoken = line_spoken.strip()
            if role == 'man':
                man.append(line_spoken)
            elif role == 'other man':
                other.append(line_spoken)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    data.close()    
except IOError:
    print('the datafile is missing')

print(man)
print(other)
```

Comment: I dont see an obvious issue with your code. It might be an issue parsing the data file. What do you get when you print line_spoken in the loop?

Comment: can you include some sample lines from `sketch.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you might have some trailing whitespaces between the role and the `:` in the file data. If you can provide some sample lines from `sketch.txt` we could know for sure. Anyway, if that is the case, you can just call `.strip()` in the `role` value as well:

```
man = []
other = []
try:
    data=open('sketch.txt')
    for each_line in data:
        try:
            (role, line_spoken) = each_line.split(':', 1)
            line_spoken = line_spoken.strip()
            role = role.strip()
            if role == 'man':
                man.append(line_spoken)
            elif role == 'other man':
                other.append(line_spoken)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    data.close()    
except IOError:
    print('the datafile is missing')

print(man)
print(other)
```

A different way that you can implement this, that you don't need the `if` statements to each role is to use a dictionary to capture the parsed data:

```
parsed_lines = {}
try:
    data=open('sketch.txt')
    for each_line in data:
        try:
            (role, line_spoken) = each_line.split(':', 1)
            line_spoken = line_spoken.strip()
            role = role.strip()
            parsed_lines[role] = parsed_lines.get(role, [])
            parsed_lines[role].append(line_spoken)            
        except ValueError:
            pass
    data.close()    
except IOError:
    print('the datafile is missing')

print(f'parsed_lines: {parsed_lines}')
```

Comment: pedro, i tried the code just as above but its still the same...below is the sample for the sketch.txt ......Man: Is this the right room for an argument?
Other Man: I've told you once.
Man: No you haven't!
Other Man: Yes I have.
Man: When?
Other Man: Just now.
Man: No you didn't!
Other Man: Yes I did!

Comment: Hey, comments mess with the format. Can you edit the question itself to include the sample text as a code block so that white spaces and line breaks etc are preserved?

Comment: But one thing that jumped to me already is that in the file you have “Man” and “Other Man” while in the code you have “man” and “other man” all in lower case

Comment: thanks pedro..the lower  case is exactly the problem..thanks so much